# log4j not getting excluded from maven build

Tags: java, scala, maven, log4j, pom.xml

I am looking to exclude the log4j in my pom file. It is not even available in the remote repository.
I have a property with version 4.0.0 in the parent pom file.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It simply does not work; I keep getting the message below.

`Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0:add-source failed: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2`

Answer (score 1):

`excludes` configuration section inside the scala-maven-plugin is meant for filtering resources to be compiled.

In your case log4j is a dependency (already compiled), you have to find what is pulling it in the build and exclude it from there (or setup a global dependency exclusion rule).